# Is it reasonable to expect that the number of upvotes is greater than the number of favorites?

Tags: discussion, up-votes, bookmarks

Am I mistaken to think that logically the number of upvotes to a question should be greater or equal to the number of favorites?

The small difference between these two numbers in this post: [Examples of common false beliefs in mathematics](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/23478/examples-of-common-false-beliefs-in-mathematics) is amazing.

Comment: Somewhat related discussion on [math.meta.se]: [Why favorite but not upvote?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/25295)

Comment: Oops, sorry.  The typo was bothering me in the HNQ list, and I forgot that this one might not already be on the front page.  Sorry for the bump!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

No, not entirely. An average question indeed has more upvotes than bookmarks (the [new name](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/347558/295232) of favorites). See below for some statistics.

Both vote types (bookmarks are stored as votes in the database) are used in different ways:

- You are expected to upvote a post when its content is useful and clear; most people use bookmarks to refer to the question later on. That includes situations where you think a post is actually *bad* and you want to check later if it is improved. (Though you can now [follow](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661/295232) the post, which is a better feature for this.)
- Upvoting requires 15 reputation, bookmarking just requires having an account.
- You can't bookmark answers; perhaps people didn't think it was a good question itself but did appreciate one or more answers.

A minor nitpick, but the question you linked to doesn't have 832 upvotes, it has a *score* of 832, composed of 841 upvotes and 9 downvotes. You can see that (if you have [1000 reputation](https://mathoverflow.net/help/privileges/established-user)) by clicking on the score.

[image]

Here is a question: [Video lectures of mathematics courses available online for free](https://mathoverflow.net/q/54430/70594) with 588 bookmarks but only a score of 358; for another popular question: [Thinking and Explaining](https://mathoverflow.net/q/38639/70594) the amounts (score: 331 vs. number of bookmarks: 330) are even closer than in your example.

It's possible to do some data analysis on the distribution of score vs. number of bookmarks with the [Stack Exchange Data Explorer](https://data.stackexchange.com/), but I'm not sure what to try. Suggestions are welcome in the comments. [Here](https://data.stackexchange.com/mathoverflow/query/1274714/score-vs-number-of-bookmarks) is some proof that the average question has a higher score than the number of bookmarks.

Here is a (log-log) plot of the number of times a certain score (yellow) or number of bookmarks (blue) appears, generated by [this SEDE query](https://data.stackexchange.com/mathoverflow/query/1274684/distribution-of-score-vs-number-of-bookmarks-log-log#graph):

[image]

So there are more questions with 1 bookmark than that there are questions with a score of 1, but for other 'counts' it's the reverse.

Comment: For very highly-upvoted questions, people might not upvote a question if they like it, but feel it has been upvoted "enough" and its score accurately reflects its quality.  That may be a partial explanation for the question Ali linked.

Comment: @WillSawin I agree that this is probably a real phenomenon. I'm conflicted as to whether it's a good, bad, or indifferent phenomenon. As I think about it, there are lots of factors at play. But maybe it should suffice to say the following: when deciding whether to upvote a question / answer, one's _primary_ consideration should simply be the straight-up question "does this question/answer have merit?" -- the question "does this question/answer already have 'enough' votes?" should carry _much_ less weight (if any) as a rule. I wonder if there has been discussion of this on meta before?

Comment: In case anybody else is curious, I did just find a [SE meta post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/15706/should-good-answers-always-be-upvoted) about this aspect of voting.